# How to save groupby result index with the key?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Added: I got a better question. Can I save the groupby result with the key, in this case 'Respondent'?

From this 
(result of `df_means = df_alert_first3.groupby("Respondent")["EAR","MAR","Circularity","MOE"].mean()`)

```
                 EAR       MAR  Circularity       MOE
Respondent                                           
2           0.266296  0.844105     0.403639  3.176411
4           0.261152  0.766167     0.395541  2.939949
6           0.345302  0.977309     0.469180  2.832706
9           0.356151  1.242451     0.536731  3.493679
11          0.305206  1.031901     0.471850  3.387900
12          0.345067  1.032473     0.468970  3.009470
```

To this

```
     Respondent  EAR            MAR  Circularity       MOE
0    2           0.266296  0.844105     0.403639  3.176411
1    4           0.261152  0.766167     0.395541  2.939949
2    6           0.345302  0.977309     0.469180  2.832706
3    9           0.356151  1.242451     0.536731  3.493679
4    11          0.305206  1.031901     0.471850  3.387900
5    12          0.345067  1.032473     0.468970  3.009470
```

I need this because the groupby result doesn't have 'Respondent' attribute.

It only has `EAR, MAR Circularity, MOE` not `Respondent`.

Even if I try to access `col[0]`, it returns `EAR` column, not `Respondent`.

Comment: Your error here is stating ou have no row of "14". My guess from this stack trace that `df_means.loc[respondent]["MAR"]` respondent equals to 14.   And there is no records in df_means where where index equals to 14.  Secondly, `df_means[respondent]["MAR"]` is not a good syntax and leads to other problems (see chained indexing).  Use `df_means.loc[respondent, "MAR"]`.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you Scott, your comment helped me understand the issue much better!